# Update value in collection

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

I have a collection of posts as data:

```
var ractive = new Ractive({
    el: '#templateContainer',
    template: '#template',
    data: {
        Posts: [{"Id":"posts/97", Content="Blog post test", Date="Something"}, ...];
    }
});
```

At some point I receive a notification that the blog post content has changed:

```
funcion onBlogPostContentChanged(postId, newContent) {
    ractive.set(..., newContent);
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to specify `ractive.set` so that the content is changed for a blog post with a specific Id.

Comment: Is `newContent` the whole post? Or just a property of the post object in the array you want to update?

Comment: @martypdx, it's a property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the keypath via the array index and the property:

```
function onItemChanged(id, newContet) {
    var posts = r.get('Posts'), index = -1

    for(var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++){
        if(post[i].Id === id){
            index = i
            break
        }        
    }

    if(index !== -1){
        r.set('Posts.' + index + '.Content', newContent)
    }

    // or if using "magic: true"**
    Posts[index].Content = newContent
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/pj6myzch/ for working example.

** http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/magic-mode

Comment: Seems like 'Posts.' + index doesn't work. Tried 'Posts[' + index + ']' but it doesn't work too.

Comment: Updated, check out the jsfiddle example.

Comment: Thank you, it works. It's a bit weird that the correct syntax is Posts.index but not Posts[index]

Comment: The strings used for gets and sets are [keypath expressions](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/keypaths#array-versus-dot-notation). I've added an example using pure javascript, which works >IE8 with `magic: true`.